# Why is the array.size '0'?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have the following array:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I also have a variable 'someNum':

```
int someNum = 12;
```

My code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){    
        int someNum = 12;
        ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(someNum);
        int arraySize = myArray.size();
        System.out.println(arraySize);
    }
}
```

Console: `'0'`

Why is it printing `'0'`?

I checked the ArrayList documentation is states that `array.size();` "Returns the number of elements in this list."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The size is 0 because you haven't added any members. The argument to the constructor is the initial *capacity*, not the initial size (or the first element).

Answer (score 3):

The constructor used in

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(someNum);
```

sets the initial capacity of the `ArrayList`. This has nothing to do with the number of elements in the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the `ArrayList` [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29) that accepts as its parameter the initial capacity of the list.

You want instead

```
myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myArray.add(someNum);
```

at which point `myArray.size()` will return `1`.